# A better way to wait/sleep in javascript

Tags: javascript, wait, sleep

I'm building a script in JS that will run on webpages and modify elements in a sequential order. I need to have the ability to wait/sleep while containing the entire process in a running function. The example below is self explanatory, and a very simple yet comprehensive example of what I need help with:

```
<body>
  <button id="button-start" onclick="updateStatus('started')">START!</button>
  <button id="button-1" onclick="console.log('step_1')">button-1</button>
  <button id="button-2" onclick="console.log('step_2')">button-2</button>

  <script>
  var status = 'stopped';
  var step = 'initial';

  function updateStatus(newStatus) {
    status = newStatus;
    script();
  }

  function wait(msec) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + msec){ /* do nothing */ }
  }

  function script() {
    while (status == 'started') {
      if (step == 'initial') {
        console.log('Script started');
        step = 'click_button1';
      }

      if (step == 'click_button1') {
        document.getElementById("button-1").click();
        wait(1000)
        step = 'click_button2';
      }

      if (step == 'click_button2') {
        document.getElementById("button-2").click();
        step = 'done';
      }

      if (step == 'done') {
        status = 'stopped';
      }

    }
    console.log('Script done');
  }

  </script>    
</body>
```

This works exactly how I need it to but obviously using while loops is not a good idea. I've seen many other questions similar to this, but I don't understand how to adapt the other answers to address what I need help with:

1. **One central function/loop that acts on different 'steps' and has multiple different waits/sleeps within these steps**
2. **Need to avoid using something that executes out of order**

Comment: You're looking for promises.

Comment: Use `setTimeout` which you can wrap into a `DelayPromise`: https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/12/01/writing-a-promise-delayer/

Comment: Could you not utilise the setTimeout functionality where you then call the same function again with different flagged inputs?

Comment: Change your central loop to a recursive function and it will integrate well with asynchronous callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it look nice you could use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves after a `setTimeout`.

Notice the line

```
await wait(1000)
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="button-start" onclick="updateStatus('started')">START!</button>
  <button id="button-1" onclick="console.log('step_1')">button-1</button>
  <button id="button-2" onclick="console.log('step_2')">button-2</button>

  <script>
  var status = 'stopped';
  var step = 'initial';

  function updateStatus(newStatus) {
    status = newStatus;
    script();
  }

  function wait(msec) {
    return new Promise(res => {setTimeout(()=>{res()}, msec)})
  }

  async function script() {
    while (status == 'started') {
      if (step == 'initial') {
        console.log('Script started');
        step = 'click_button1';
      }

      if (step == 'click_button1') {
        document.getElementById("button-1").click();
        await wait(1000)
        step = 'click_button2';
      }

      if (step == 'click_button2') {
        document.getElementById("button-2").click();
        step = 'done';
      }

      if (step == 'done') {
        status = 'stopped';
      }

    }
    console.log('Script done');
  }

  </script>    
</body>
```

Comment: This is perfect! I'm actually writing this for my Electron app but it doesn't look like it supports ES6 yet. I found this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait but I'm having some trouble getting it to work :/ Thanks for the answer!